# Exchange Hybrid Deployment - EWS Access for 3rd party UC application

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

We have a UC application which has an Exchange integration feature. The integration uses EWS to connect to mailboxes and synchronise calendar events and other info.

The system has a single field for the 'Exchange server address' (which it seems to turn into an EWS URL), which is then used combined with the user's credentials to log in to their mailbox and perform the sync when they log into the system.

The issue is that we have a hybrid Exchange 2016 & Office 365 deployment where say, for example, 50% of the mailboxes are on Office 365, and the remainder on-site.

Since the UC system only has a single field for the server address, and no way of working out which server the mailbox is hosted on, whichever address you use, whether on-site or Office 365, the system is only able to authenticate 50% of the users.

Is there a way around this issue?

I was thinking perhaps some kind of proxy via Office 365 or on-site, or even a round robin DNS entry, but I'm not sure whether these options are feasible.